Qt::Multimedia and Qt::MultimediaWidgets libraries missing in Qt 6.7.3 ARM64 version of online installer
I'm trying to port some linux application from x86 to arm64.
I've setup two development PCs, one with x86 Ubuntu and one with arm64 Ubuntu.
on each I downloaded the respective Qt6 online installer from https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer. On x86 I executed qt-online-installer-linux-x64-4.8.1.run to install Qt6 and on the arm64 machine I executed qt-online-installer-linux-arm64-4.8.1.run
Now the problem is that while on the x86 machine the folder ~/Qt/6.7.3/gcc_64/lib contains (among many other libs) the following files
libQt6Multimedia.prl
libQt6Multimedia.so
libQt6Multimedia.so.6
libQt6Multimedia.so.6.7.3
libQt6MultimediaQuick.prl
libQt6MultimediaQuick.so
libQt6MultimediaQuick.so.6
libQt6MultimediaQuick.so.6.7.3
libQt6MultimediaWidgets.prl
libQt6MultimediaWidgets.so
libQt6MultimediaWidgets.so.6
libQt6MultimediaWidgets.so.6.7.3

but on the arm64 machine in the corresponding folder ~/Qt/6.7.3/gcc_arm64/lib these files are missing.
I've read somewhere that in Qt 6.0 QtMultimedia was removed, but it was readded in Qt 6.2
Why is it missing in my ARM64 installation of Qt 6.7.3? is this module not available on ARM or is this some other problem?
